# /usr/bin/wg-quick: line 31: resolvconf: command not found [WireGuard | Debian]

Tags: debian, wireguard

**Error Message**:

> `/usr/bin/wg-quick: line 31: resolvconf: command not found`

**The issue**:

I am not fully certain, I do have `openresolv` installed rn and have tried it and got the same response when `resolvconf` is installed.

Either way, I cannot connect to my VPN.

Answer (score 85):

Modern Linux distributions use systemd, which comes with its own flavor of
`resolvconf` as part of the `resolvectl` command. See [manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/systemd/resolvectl.1.en.html#COMPATIBILITY_WITH_RESOLVCONF(8)). A symlink called `resolvconf` can be created somewhere in `$PATH`.

- On Arch linux there's the [systemd-resolvconf](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/systemd-resolvconf/) package that does this for you.
- On Debian (and Ubuntu?) you must do this manually. Using `/usr/local` to prevent possible package conflicts:

  ```
  ln -s /usr/bin/resolvectl /usr/local/bin/resolvconf
  ```

With the symlink in place, `wg-quick` works fine for me.

**Edit**: There is a Debian [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=939904) requesting the symlink

Comment: I had to run the command `systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service` otherwise I got "Failed to set DNS configuration"

Answer (score 45):

Had the same problem, found on this page: https://github.com/StreisandEffect/streisand/issues/1434

```
sudo apt install openresolv
```

Resolved it for me.

Comment: "Too few arguments"

Answer (score 7):

just install it with `apt-get install resolvconf` and reboot, or comment out all DNS fields in configuration file

Answer (score 5):

It’s not the solution, but if you comment out the DNS in the wg0 conf file it will work. wg-quick does a bunch of things behind the scenes, one of them is adjusting the nameserver, typically to use your vpn providers. Set your /etc/resolv.conf to use Cloudflare (1.1.1.1), then try again. It should connect without the resolvconf dependency.

Comment: no errors shown anymore, but networking is not working...

Answer (score 4):

Seems like resolvconf command is missing in your system or it isn't installed, try this:

```
sudo apt install resolvconf
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Try using `systemctl` instead:

```
systemctl start wg-quick@<vpn-name>
```

Or if you wish to start the VPN every time you start your machine use:

```
systemctl enable wg-quick@<vpn-name>
```

---

Comment: This is not a solution for problem. Problem is because a question of "openresolve". Change metodh of start no change de problem.